# Weird catlog provides no explanation

Tags: java, android, android-logcat

Recently started getting a rather odd Catlog which doesn't describe what's going wrong very well.

I have it posted here: http://pastie.org/9415113

Line 55:

```
        DebugCarTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DebugCar);

        // you should  instantiate 'DatabaseHandler'  here
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this); // "this" refer to the context
        Car cars = db.getCurrentCar();

        db.createCar(new Car(cars.get_id(),cars.get_address(),cars.get_postcode(),cars.get_image()));
//this is line 55       String rows= "id : "+ cars.get_id()+ " address : "+cars.get_address() + "postcode : "+cars.get_postcode()+" image : "+cars.get_image();
```

This is my getCurrentCar() {};

```
public Car getCurrentCar() {

    SQLiteDatabase db       =   getWritableDatabase();
    String sql              = "SELECT " + KEY_ID + "," + KEY_IMAGE + " FROM " + TABLE_CARS + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
    Cursor cursor           =   db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {});
    Car car = null;

    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            car = new Car(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
        }
    }
    finally {
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
            db.close();
    }
    return car;
}
```

Am I right to assume it's calling a null because there isn't anything in the database?

Comment: You have a null pointer in line 55 of MyActivity.java. What can be more clear?

Comment: Thanks @Eran I've updated my OP because the Android Studio IDE doesn't provide any distinct errors.

Comment: FYI its logcat not catlog, although I like the sound of that

Comment: As far as I can see `cars` is null. Why will be found within `db.getCurrentCar();`

Comment: @RichardTingle Could this be because my database is empty, therefore it cannot grab anything and returns null?

Comment: From your edit; I'm assuming `cursor.moveToFirst()` returns false, which would lead to the whole method returning null. I suggest stepping through the code in a debugger

Comment: @RichardTingle would you be willing to have a discussion about this?

Comment: Absolutely, however, I don't have sql experience so if the problem lies there I may not be your man

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57859/discussion-between-bradly-spicer-and-richard-tingle).

Answer (score 2):

One of the values you are getting is set as null.

---

Edit: MY fault, I believe that it is the Car that is null.
You should check if there are any values set as null by:

```
if(car == null) { //and etc for other get method.
    //Use Logs here to print error on logcat.
}
```

This should help identifying which value is null.

Info on Logs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: I'm pretty certain it has to be `cars` that is null. Anything else would create an exception earlier/later

Comment: Thanks @RichardTingle. I tried to recreate his problem through a simple java program and I believe that you are right.